# Using variable to ask for key in JSON object

Tags: json, power-automate

I'm trying to build a flow that uses a JSON data structure (Let's call it Test). I'm trying to ask for the value in a given key using a variable declared previously in the flow, however, when I try something like:

```
variables('Test')?[variables('Texto')]
```

Test contains two key-value pairs, and Texto contains a string with one of the keys. When I run the flow I get this:

[image]

Which is not an error, but it doesn't allow me to see the inputs or outputs (the download links send me to empty pages), but given the simplicity of the exercise, I was expecting to see the value associated with the right key in the JSON.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need to provide your JSON, a bit hard to help without it.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using `Compose`, try just setting/initializing a variable instead.

As an example, I created an object variable using the following JSON ...

```
{
  "Field1": "Value 1",
  "Field2": "Value 2"
}
```

I then set a string variable with the value `Field1` ...

[image: Variable]

Then in the next step, I used the same sort of expression as you ...

```
variables('JSON')?[variables('Dynamic Field Name')]
```

... and got the following result ...

[image: Result]